# How can one access Snakemake config variables inside `shell` section?

Tags: snakemake

In snakemake I would like to access keys from the `config` from within the `shell:` directive. I can use `{input.foo}`, `{output.bar}`, and `{params.baz}`, but `{config.quux}` is not supported. Is there a way to achieve this?

```
rule do_something:
    input: "source.txt"
    output: "target.txt"
    params:
        # access config[] here. parameter tracking is a side effect
        tmpdir = config['tmpdir']
    shell:
        # using {config.tmpdir} or {config['tmpdir']} here breaks the build
        "./scripts/do.sh --tmpdir {params.tmpdir} {input} > {output}; "
```

I could assign the parts of the config I want to a key under `params`, and then use a `{param.x}` replacement, but this has unwanted side effects (e.g. the parameter is saved in the snakemake metadata (i.e. `.snakemake/params_tracking`). Using `run:` instead of `shell:` would be another workaround, but accessing `{config.tmpdir}` directly from the `shell` block, would be most desirable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`"./scripts/do.sh --tmpdir {config[tmpdir]} {input} > {output}; "`

should work here.

It is stated in the documentation:
http://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/configuration.html#standard-configuration

"For adding config placeholders into a shell command, Python string formatting syntax requires you to leave out the quotes around the key name, like so:"

```
shell:
    "mycommand {config[foo]} ..."
```

Comment: Baaah. *sigh*. missed that little documentation blurb . Thanks! I don't particularly like the asymmetry between `{params.foo}` and `{config[foo]}`, but at least there's a way.